# ImportXML function in Google Sheets to pull out specific data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm unable to import with ImportHTML table (it's prohibited by website) from the following page:
https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/SIH22/volatility-greeks/mar-22

I've tried and failed to use ImportXML function to retrieve a specific value from this page.
For example the last price of a specific strike from the table. As shown in the attached image.

Any hope to retrieve the data with ImportXML?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the webpage you provided is being controlled by JavaScript which means IMPORT functions of Google Sheets won't be able to fetch the data that you want. To check whether it is JavaScript enabled webpage, you can click on the lock button on the left side of the URL in the browser -> Click on site settings -> Set JavaScript to Block.

Upon doing this, the table in the website you provided disappeared.

[image]

I suggest finding another source website which gives the same information and can be fetched using IMPORT functions.